# Is it a best practice to mark @ObservedObject and @StateObject as private?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have seen conflicting information on whether `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` should be marked `private` or not. I read that they shouldn't be marked as `private` since they are bound objects that can be used by more than one view, so it’s common to share them openly. However shouldn't everything that can be marked as `private` be marked as `private` until otherwise needed?

Example:

```
struct InnerView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var userProgress: UserProgress

    var body: some View {
        Button("Increase Score") {
            userProgress.score += 1
        }
    }

    init(userProgress: UserProgress) {
        self.userProgress = userProgress
    }
}

struct DemoView2: View {
    @StateObject private var userProgress = UserProgress()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(userProgress.score)")
            InnerView(userProgress: userProgress)
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView2()
    }
}

final class UserProgress: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}
```

Comment: `StateObject` yes, `ObservedObject` no. `ObservedObject` needs to receive its value from the parent. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Your initialiser seems wrong `self.userProgress = userProgress`. I feel it should be `_userProgress = ObservedObject(initialValue: userProgress)`. If you find that too complex leave `@ObservedObject` non-private / internal so that you don't have the hassle of creating your initialiser

Comment: Moreover View is a struct, you don't have any additional protection making `@ObservedObject` private ... you can't get access to the same view and update it with a different value as the view is a value type

Comment: Yes `@State` should be private to make the intent clear that that is completely within the view's existence, `@ObservedObject` is from the outside so can be left internal. That is my opinion

Answer (score 2):

> However shouldn't everything that can be marked as private be marked as private until otherwise needed?

Yes, that is a good general rule.

> I read that they shouldn't be marked as private since they are bound objects that can be used by more than one view, so it’s common to share them openly.

While `ObservableObject` conformant types *might* be shared between different views, they rarely (if every) are shared between views that are not in the same view hierarchy and the direction of the sharing is usually parent view to child views, not the other way around. So there's no reason to mark these objects as anything other than `private`, since if they are `private`, they can still be shared with child views.

Moreover, due to the fact that SwiftUI Views are value types usually created inside the `body` of their parent view, there's no way of accessing them from outside their parent view (and in most cases its `body`), so even if you mark a property as anything other than `private`, you still won't actually be accessing it from outside the view or its parent.